# Remove path from url and add another

Tags: php, javascript, url, path, onclick

I have a div that contains links(dynamic) and want when users clicked on a link to delete the path from the href attrybute and to add another.

For example: I want to convert this:

```
<div id="example"> 
<a href="/some path/page_id=8">Link1</a>
<a href="/some path/page_id=8">Link2</a>
<a href="/some path/page_id=8">Link3</a>
......

</div>
```

to :

```
<div id="example"> 
<a href="/some path/ANOTHER_PATH">Link1</a>
<a href="/some path/ANOTHER_PATH">Link2</a>
<a href="/some path/ANOTHER_PATH">Link3</a>
......

</div>
```

I'm a nooby in php and javascript, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Using jquery:  `$('#link').click(function(){change your path});`   Or you can use javascript window.location.Replace(something_str, with_something_else_str); In php, you can call header(Location:'new-path');

Comment: ok, but how to do it dynamic...I mean all links from <div id="example"> to change on click

p.s.Sorry for my english

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for you (assuming you have jQuery)

```
$("#example a").click(function(){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $(this).attr('href', href.replace('/some path', '/some path/ANOTHER_PATH'));
});
```

[See it working here on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pfkA7/)

---

**EDIT**

If you need a native JavaScript version, here you go

```
var e = document.getElementById('example');
var links = e.getElementsByTagName('a');

for(x in links){
    links[x].onclick = function(){
        this.href = this.href.replace('/some%20path', '/some%20path/ANOTHER_PATH');
    };
}
```

[See it working here on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pfkA7/1/)
​

Comment: Great answer - Just a note to the OP that it requires the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) javascript library.

Comment: @nickb, I added a native JavaScript version too :)

Answer (score 1):

pure JS:

```
document.getElementById('example').childNodes[1].href = 'www.najdi.si';
document.getElementById('example').childNodes[2].href = 'www.google.com';
```